# Смена фона нескольких страниц в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос заключается в том что в одной из n-страниц есть кнопки с названием цвет, и мне необходимо что бы при нажатии одной из кнопок, фон всех страниц поменял на определенный цвет. Wpf только изучаю, буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, по идее ничего сложного нет.

Вам нужно положить ваш фон в глобальные ресурсы (в App.xaml):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CommonBackground">White</SolidColorBrush>
    <!-- тут другие ресурсы -->
</Application.Resources>
```

Теперь, установите фон ваших страниц:

```
<Window ...
    Background="{DynamicResource CommonBackground}">
```

(или `Page`)

В обработчике нажатия на кнопку пишете:

```
void OnChangeBackgroundClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Application.Current.Resources["CommonBackground"] = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Вроде, всё.

(Код не проверял, сорри, пишу с телефона, возможны очепятки.)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Иллюзорный: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Иллюзорный если работает, то поставьте ответу зеленую галочку